# Superstring vacuum amplitude on the torus

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, supersymmetry, conformal-field-theory, partition-function

My question is how to obtain the superstring (Type II A and B) vacuum amplitudes on a torus. They are given in Polchinski's String Theory Vol. 2 equation (10.7.9):

$$Z_\psi^{\pm}=\frac{1}{2}[Z^0_0(\tau)^4-Z^0_1(\tau)^4-Z^1_0(\tau)^4\mp Z^0_0(\tau)^4].$$

I understand how each individual $Z^\alpha_\beta$ is obtained but do not understand how they are put together to get $Z_\psi^{\pm}$.

Comment: @Heterotic gives a good answer. Also for those interested, _An introduction to string theory and D-brane Dynamics_ by R. J. Szabo also explained it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think about this is the following. In general, the partition function (which is the integrand of the vacuum amplitude and not the vacuum amplitude itself) will be of the form

$Z_\psi^{\pm}\propto\sum_{a,b}C[^a_b]Z^a_b(\tau)$

where $a$ and $b$ sum over the different sectors as given in the text and the $C$s are some phases. Many of these phases are fixed by modular invariance, ie by the requirement that $Z$ is invariant under $\tau\rightarrow\tau+1$ and $\tau\rightarrow-\frac{1}{\tau}$. Given that $C[^0_0]=1$ (it's only the **relative** phases that matter, so we can fix this one), modular invariance demands that $C[^0_1]=C[^1_0]=-1$. However, both choices $C[^0_0]=\pm$ give modular invariant theories, so we end up with two different viable theories.